# How to create left hand Column

Tags: two-column

How to create left hand column like that picture. 
Please. Thank you[image]

Comment: Your questions lacks some context: is this for a small portion of text? A whole page? A whole document? Also, you could simply use a tabular. In fact, it's the easiest and fastest option I can think of.

Comment: Oops sorry. I just beginner in LATEX.

Comment: No need to apologise. :D But can you answer whether it's for a small portion of text or something larger? It'd help finding a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Without more information, the question is too broad. There are many ways to do that: tables (`tabular` environment, two `minipages`, `tcolorbox` or `flowfram` package, some of the packges of the [parallel text](https://www.ctan.org/topic/parallel) in CTAN, etc. All are better or worse depending of your goals.  To try to catch lightning in a bottle, just one example using `parcolumns`:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % make dummy text
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\begin{document}
\begin{parcolumns}[nofirstindent,sloppy,rulebetween,colwidths={1=.35\linewidth,2=.55\linewidth}]{2}
\colchunk[1]{\lipsum[2]} 
\colchunk[2]{\lipsum[1]}
\end{parcolumns}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @AltantsoojTseveenjav. You are welcome, but the way  of say thanks in thi site is upvote useful answers and among these, accept the best for you. Please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954)